# What Does Putting An Asterisk in Front Of 'this' Do In This Situation?

Tags: c++

I was wondering what putting an asterisk in front of 'this' does in this particular situation with the overloaded '!=' operator.

```
class String
{
private:
    int m_length;
    char *m_strPtr;

    //Utility function
    void set_string( const char *string );

public:
    String( const char *string ); // Default constructor
    String( const String &string ); // Copy constructor
    ~String();

    int get_length() const { return m_length; };

    // Overloaded operators
    bool operator!=( const String &rhs ) const { return !( *this == rhs ); };
    bool operator==( const String &rhs ) const { return ( strcmp( m_strPtr, rhs.m_strPtr ) == 0 ); };

};
```

Why would you use '*this' instead of just 'this' in this situation?

Comment: `this` is a pointer and `*this` is a reference to the object itself

Comment: so if you were to just use 'this' would you be referring to the address of the pointer?

Comment: `this` is a pointer to the object, so it holds the address of the object.

Comment: does the same thing go for references? if i use '&var' i get the content of the reference, and if i use just 'var' i'm referring to the address?

Comment: Note that `return !( *this == rhs )` is just a fancy way to write `return ! operator==(rhs)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*this` gives the current object. In your case, `!( *this == rhs );` inturn invokes `bool operator==( const String &rhs )` that you have defined in your `String` class.

If it were through pointer (`this`) you would have to invoke `operator==` manually `this->operator==(rhs)`. By putting `*this` in your example, you help the compiler to know that it actually needs to call `operator==`

Answer (score 5):

Using `*this` returns the actual reference to the object through what is known as **dereferencing**. Before the dereference, `this` is a **pointer**. Using `*this` gives you the **"content of"** this current object

[Pointers/Dereference Link](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/)

**FYI:** Just to add some clarity to the `*` and `&` operators for your future reference on other problems

> ***var** ...Means "content of" var
>
> **int*** ...Means int pointer
>
> **&int** ...Means address of int
>
> **int&** ...Means int address

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a pointer to the object. Using an `*` deferences the pointer, resulting in the actual object instead of a memory address.

Comment: is it the same thing with references? if i use '&var' i get the content of the object, and if i were to just use 'var' i would get the address?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing current object. `this` is pointer to current object. `*this` will be current object.